# Conditionally display/hide universal icon in inline help text in APEX

Tags: html, oracle-apex

I'm working with APEX ORACLE ver 23.1. My problem is to conditionally display or hide `fa-warning` in inline help text of one page item (`P1_item1`). The condition is based on another page item:

- display if `P1_item2 <> ''`
- hide if `P1_item2 = ''`

And the help text will be the following

```
if P1_item2 <> ''
<span class="fa fa-warning" aria-hidden="true"></span> &P1_item2.
```

If anyone of you have an idea about how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you attach screenshot which illustrates it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the help attribute of the inline help text, the type should be a HTML statement: [image: HTML]

So to have conditional values, you need to create another page item such as P1_INLINE_HELP_TEXT and then you can reference this page item as `&P1_INLINE_HELP_TEXT.`

The new page item should contain the HTML text computed/calculated by a dynamic action or a process either on page load or on a change of value etc.

The source of the page item `P1_INLINE_HELP_TEXT` should look like something like this:

```
case when ( :P1_ITEM2 != 30  ) then '<span class="fa fa-warning" aria-hidden="true"></span>' else null end
```

**EDIT**

As you mentioned the HTML calculated displayed as text and not rendered, use a JQuery snippet like this:

```
$('#P1_ITEM_inline_help').html($('#P1_ITEM_inline_help').text());
```

This will get the text of the span (i.e " < span class="fa fa-warning" > </ span>") and set it as HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this approach and apex displayed the full text `<span class="fa fa-warning" aria-hidden="true"></span>` instead of icon.

Comment: Is it correct if I put `$('#P1_INLINE_HELP_TEXT').html($('#P1_INLINE_HELP_TEXT').text());` within `inline help text`? I tried this and it still does not work. I also try to put this code in `Function and Global Variable declaration` but still does not work.
Or you mean there should be a different `P1_ITEM_inline_help` and the code must be in other place?

Comment: no you should put this snippet to execute when page load or on a page load dynamic action. Make sure that the value is already calculated (even if it is in text form). Afterwards you should execute it. And also the JQuery code should not have the P1_INLINE_HELP_TEXT item, it should have the items id + _inline_help (check DOM elements to make sure)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I manage to solve the problem using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle `''` is identical to `NULL`.

Oracle uses trinary logic where comparisons can evaluate to `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL` and if you use `Anything = NULL` or `Anything <> NULL` then the result is always `NULL` and never `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

If you want to test whether a value is `NULL` (or `''`) or is not `NULL` (or not `''`) then use:

```sql
P1_item2 IS NULL
```

or

```sql
P1_item2 IS NOT NULL
```